# The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu-14.04, apex-data-loader

I am trying to install dataloader on my Linux machine.
https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader

There is a command line on third line:

```
$ mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

When I typed that in, I got this error:

```
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
* maven
* maven2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Dataloader needs Maven. It's a dependency manager for Java.

Thus you have to install Maven before being able to use it.

Just run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install maven2` and `mvn` will be available on your computer.

---

Maven documentation (for more up to date installation instructions) : https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Comment: When I tried it, I got following messages:                                                        W: GPG error: https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B02C46DF417A0893
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/tonddast:/itk/xUbuntu_9.04/./Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]

Comment: E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure what to do here. It appears that 'mvn' can be found in the following packages: *maven and *maven2. But why do we need to install Maven?

Comment: Maven is a utility used to manage and build Java projects. And dataloader seems to be a Java project.
So it needs maven to build and install itself (it was programmed that way). And `mvn` is the command to launch Maven. If the classic package installation did not work, you should give a try following these official instructions : https://maven.apache.org/install.html