# Plugin requires Maven version 3.0

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am trying to run following command line

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

Reference: https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/

I am getting this error message:

```
BUILD ERROR
Error resolving version for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin': 
Plugin requires Maven version 3.0
```

How do I install Maven version 3.0  or is there way to modify file like POM.XML?

Comment: Go to Maven 3 cause Maven 2 is long time end of life...

Answer (score 2):

Without modifying your pom.xml, you can simply install and use mvn 3.x instead of mvn 2.x

Follow "[Installing Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)", and make sure your PATH reference that new version.
For instance, on Linux:

```
export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin:$PATH
```

If `mvn --version` does return the right version, try again your `mvn clean package -DskipTests` command.

With that approach (download and unzip an  archive) you don't even need `sudo apt-get install` that [you tried yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44850105/6309). Just download [`apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.zip`](https://fossies.org/linux/misc/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.tar.gz).

Comment: Hi VonC, Thanks for comment. I have two questions. Do I have to follow all first section of "Installing Apache Maven" or just dive into "Unix-based Operating System (Linux, Solaris and Mac OS X) Tips"? Also, I am not sure what to do on this line "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home". Do I just type this on the Command Line?

Comment: @KingJava Yes, you can follow the first section, knowing that you can actually extract the `tar.gz` file anywhere you want, as long as you add the resulting folder to your `PATH` (in your `.profile`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638025/6309)

Comment: @KingJava The `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/‌​Home` is just an example of what `echo $JAVA_HOME` could return: the goal of this section is to make sure you have a `$JAVA_HOME` already set, and that it is added to the `PATH`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu it is enough to uninstall maven2 and install maven (which is version 3 currently):

```
sudo apt remove maven2

sudo apt install maven
```

Check your version with

```
mvn --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Package 'maven2' is not installed, so not removed